# How to calculate the element of the array?

Tags: php

I have an array like the following

```
 $array = array(1,2,4,7,1,6,2,8);
```

I want to divide the array to 3 groups and the sum of the each group will need to be as equal as possible.

so the result is

```
8,2    = 10
7,2,1  = 10
6,4,1  = 11
```

I tried:

```
$array = array(1,2,4,7,1,6,2,8);   
   $total = array_sum($array);
   $setNumber = $total/3;

   for($i; $i<count($array); $i++){
       $group += $array[$i]
        if($group > $setNumber){
           break;
        }
   }
```

I am not sure how to complete this task. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: Closers: why do you think this question is broad? The solutions can be many, but the question is easily answerable, it even has an upvoted answer, so why do you try to close it?

Comment: I think you should try some javascript tutorialshttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736885/how-to-define-my-variable-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just sort the $array and start adding the items to the smallest group from the biggest number down. It may not be the best result, but at least it stays in O(n). I'm looking forward to some better answer.

```
$arr1 = $arr2 = $arr3 = array();
$sum1 = $sum2 = $sum3 = 0;
sort($array);
for($i=count($array)-1; $i>=0; --$i) {
  if($sum1<=$sum2 && $sum1<=$sum3) { $arr1[] = $array[$i]; $sum1+= $array[$i]; }
  else if($sum2<=$sum1 && $sum2<=$sum3) { $arr2[] = $array[$i]; $sum2+= $array[$i]; }
  else if($sum3<=$sum1 && $sum3<=$sum2) { $arr3[] = $array[$i]; $sum3+= $array[$i]; }
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I would take also, 'Knapsack' problem best describes this question.