# How to define my variable structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create something as following:

```
var collectoin= 
[
  'title1' => {'subtitle:'sub1', 'contents':'sub content 1' },
  'title2' => {'subtitle:'sub2', 'contents':'sub content 2' },
  'title3' => {'subtitle:'sub3', 'contents':'sub content 3' }
]
```

but I feel like it's not valid. I am not sure what's the best structure for my case.

thanks for the help

Comment: You feel right, arrows are not valid in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the object presented by @juvian does not have a defined ordering of the keys (in contrast to PHP associative arrays, for example). I guess you want an ordered collection, for which you have to use an array:

```
var collection = [
    {'title': '1', 'subtitle':'sub1', 'contents':'sub content 1'},
    {'title': '2', 'subtitle':'sub2', 'contents':'sub content 2'},
    {'title': '3', 'subtitle':'sub3', 'contents':'sub content 3'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not work in javascript, you should try to read about javascript objects and arrays before asking here. Anyway, the correct syntax would be:

```
var collection= 
   {
       'title1' : {'subtitle':'sub1', 'contents':'sub content 1' },
       'title2' : {'subtitle':'sub2', 'contents':'sub content 2' },
       'title3' : {'subtitle':'sub3', 'contents':'sub content 3' }
   }
```